# Redirecting Program Output from /dev/*char_device* to Text File

Tags: firmware, linux, driver

I am currently trying to reverse an IoT machine running the 2.6 Linux Kernel on which I have root. On this machine, software writes to /dev/*some_device* to control what I believe to be are GPIO pins for a serial bus. In order to take control of these GPIO pins, I have been attempting to reverse the on-board software to grasp how the drivers are looking for input, but the decompilation has been messy/missing parts.

Thus, my question: 
**Am I able to redirect program output intended for /dev/*some_device* to a text file for analysis?**

For example, the current mapping:

```
Program -> (char sequence) -> /dev/*char_device*
```

I am looking for a way to redirect the program output from the device to a text file, or better, any writes to the device to a text file. Example:

```
Program -> (char sequence) --\       /dev/*char_device*
                              \
                               \-----> *my_text_file*
```

Again, my motivation to do so is to analyze how the driver is expecting input. I already know my logical input/output/return communications on the serial bus, I just need to be able to determine the specifics of the device driver. Any help is appreciated. Let me know if more information is required.

-Update-
Here is a method I tracked down in the source code decompliation. While I cannot verify that this is the exact handler for the devices I'm targeting, it used by devices with similar names.

```
// Address range: 0x1000c470 - 0x1000c6f7
int32_t function_1000c470(int32_t * a1, int32_t a2, int32_t a3, char * path) {
    int32_t v1 = (int32_t)a1;
    int32_t v2; // bp-144
    int32_t v3 = &v2; // 0x1000c470_0
    v2 = v3;
    g602 = v3;
    int32_t fd = open(path, O_RDWR);
    int32_t * fd2 = (int32_t *)(v1 + 4); // 0x1000c4a8_0
    *fd2 = fd;
    if (*fd2  0x1000c6d8
    } else {
        // 0x1000c500
        fprintf(g94, "opening serial device %s with fd %d\n", path, *fd2);
        int32_t termios_p;
        tcgetattr(*fd2, (struct termios *)&termios_p);
        cfmakeraw((struct termios *)&termios_p);
        cfsetospeed((struct termios *)&termios_p, 9);
        cfsetispeed((struct termios *)&termios_p, 9);
        tcsetattr(*fd2, TCSANOW, (struct termios *)&termios_p);
        ioctl(*fd2, 0x5415);
        g1 &= -0x2000001;
        ioctl(*fd2, 0x5418);
        *(int32_t *)(v1 + 16) = 0;
        *(int32_t *)(v1 + 20) = 0;
        int32_t * v4 = (int32_t *)(4 * *fd2 / 32 + v1 + 1668); // 0x1000c630_0
        *v4 = 1  0x1000c674
        }
        // 0x1000c674
        *(int32_t *)(v1 + 8) = v7 + 1;
        *(int32_t *)(v1 + 1624) = 0;
        *(int32_t *)(v1 + 1620) = 0;
        *(int32_t *)(v1 + 1628) = 0;
        memset((char *)(v1 + 120), 0, 1500);
        function_1000c6f8(*fd2, 0);
        // branch -> 0x1000c6d8
    }
    int32_t v8 = v2; // 0x1000c6dc
    g602 = *(int32_t *)(v8 - 4);
    return *(int32_t *)(v8 + 4);
}
```

Comment: To add, the /dev/device I am targeting is a character device. It'd like to divert its input steam to an output file.

Comment: Part of my thought believes that the /dev device is just a pointer to the driver handler. If that is case, would I be able to overwrite the pointer to my own device?

Comment: It is also a file. Which interface this software use for accessing device? Is it uses open(2)?

Comment: @de6f I have updated the original post with the decompiled source code which is working on the device file.

Comment: Ideally, I should be able to take the supplied code and recompile it into my own program and try to harness termios to setup a serial connection. I'm a bit weary on this being the correct code those as the /dev/device I am trying to target is an IBM SDLC serial bus. In fact, I'm going to make the assumption that the code in the post is not for the device that I am targetting.

Comment: I'll have to do some more investigation to find out how the special devices in this system are mounted and find code for controlling. I currently can not find the module.

Answer (score 2):

I have used [`/dev/ptmx`](https://linux.die.net/man/4/pts) for that purpose:

Say i want to intercept data written to `/dev/somedevice`

- First i open the master: `/dev/ptmx`.
- Then i allocate a slave by calling `ptsname`.
- Now rename `/dev/somedevice` to `/dev/somedevice.orig`
- Symlink `/dev/somedevice` to the pts slave.
- open the original device `/dev/somedevice.orig`
- start copying data between the master and the original device.
  recording data to a log file.

Make sure the interceptor gets started before the original program opens the device.

Also, i think you may run into problems handling `ioctl`s this way.

Comment: Thank you William. I'll give this a try when I sit down next. I'll report back.